# Convert a string to a List (of every Character) Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I'd like to convert a string (say `number = 1423658`) into a list that would be like:`sequence = [1, 4, 2, 3, 6, 5, 8]`. I think this could be achieved with letters but I don't see how to achieve it with numbers...

Comment: have you tried `list('1423658')`?

Comment: Note that `number = 1423658` is not a string, and neither is `[1, 4, 2, 3, 6, 5, 8]` a list of characters. Maybe you want `[int(x) for x in str(number)]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just type-cast the string to `list`

```
>>> my_string = '1423658'
>>> list(my_string)
['1', '4', '2', '3', '6', '5', '8']
```

---

If you want to also convert the type of each number in `list` to `int`, you may do it using *list comprehension* as:

```
>>> [int(c) for c in my_string]
[1, 4, 2, 3, 6, 5, 8]
```

OR, using `map()` as:

```
>>> list(map(int, my_string))  # In Python 3
[1, 4, 2, 3, 6, 5, 8]

# In python 2: map(int, my_string) is enough
```

Answer (score 3):

Convert your number to `str` and then to `list`:

```
>>> number = 1423658
>>> list(map(int, str(number)))
[1, 4, 2, 3, 6, 5, 8]
```